# Using multiple threads for DB updates results in higher write time per update

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, sequel

So I have a script that is supposed to update a giant table (Postgres). Since the table has about 150m rows and I want to complete this as fast as possible, using multiple threads seemed like a perfect answer. However, I'm seeing something very weird.

When I use a single thread, the write time to an update is much much lower than when I use multiple threads.

```
require 'sequel'
.....

DB = Sequel.connect(DB_CREDS)
queue = Queue.new

read_query = query = DB["
    SELECT id, extra_fields
    FROM objects
    WHERE XYZ IS FALSE
"]

read_query.use_cursor(:rows_per_fetch => 1000).each do |row|
    queue.push(row)
end
```

Up until this point, IMO it shouldn't matter because we're just reading stuff from the DB and it has nothing to do with writing. From here, I've tried two approaches. Single-threaded and Multi-threaded.

NOTE - This is not the actual UPDATE query that I want to execute, it's just a pseudo one for demonstration purposes. The actual query is a lot longer and plays with JSON and stuff so I can't really update the entire table using a single query.

**Single-threaded**

```
until queue.empty?
    photo = queue.shift
    id = photo[:id]
    update_query = DB["
        UPDATE objects
        SET XYZ = TRUE
        WHERE id = #{id}    
    "]

    result = update_query.update
end
```

If I execute this, I see in my DB logs that each update query takes time less than *0.01 seconds*

> I, [2016-08-15T10:45:48.095324 #54495]  INFO -- : (0.001441s)         UPDATE
>   objects       SET XYZ = TRUE      WHERE id = 84395179
>
> I, [2016-08-15T10:45:48.103818 #54495]  INFO -- : (0.008331s)         UPDATE
>   objects       SET XYZ = TRUE      WHERE id = 84395181
>
> I, [2016-08-15T10:45:48.106741 #54495]  INFO -- : (0.002743s)         UPDATE
>   objects       SET XYZ = TRUE      WHERE id = 84395182

**Multi-threaded**

```
MAX_THREADS = 5
num_threads = 0
all_threads = []

until queue.empty?
    if num_threads < MAX_THREADS
        photo = queue.shift
        num_threads += 1
        all_threads << Thread.new {
            id = photo[:id]
            update_query = DB["
                UPDATE photos
                SET cv_tagged = TRUE
                WHERE id = #{id}    
            "]

            result = update_query.update
            num_threads -= 1
            Thread.exit
        }
    end
end

all_threads.each do |thread|
    thread.join
end
```

Now, in theory it should be faster right? But each update takes about *0.5 seconds*. I'm so surprised what that is the case.

> I, [2016-08-15T11:02:10.992156 #54583]  INFO -- : (0.414288s)
>                 UPDATE objects
>                 SET XYZ = TRUE
>                 WHERE id = 119498834
>
> I, [2016-08-15T11:02:11.097004 #54583]  INFO -- : (0.622775s)
>                 UPDATE objects
>                 SET XYZ = TRUE
>                 WHERE id = 119498641
>
> I, [2016-08-15T11:02:11.097074 #54583]  INFO -- : (0.415521s)
>                 UPDATE objects
>                 SET XYZ = TRUE
>                 WHERE id = 119498826

Any ideas on -

1. Why this is happening?
2. How can I increase the update speed for multiple threads approach.

Comment: Have you considered that perhaps the way the table gets locked/unlocked for writing is actually triggering more database overhead than if you just did it all in one fell swoop? This is spitballing because I don't really have any insight into how exactly your db is configured, etc.

Comment: Do you get this performance issue with the queries you've shown or only with the real queries in your app?

Comment: I see the performance issue with the queries that I've posted in my examples too

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you configured Sequel so that it has a connection pool of 5 connections?
2. Have you considered doing multiple updates per call via an IN clause?

If you haven't done 1, you have N threads fighting over N-n connections, which equates to resource starvation, which is a classic concurrency issue.

Comment: 1. Yes, I'm specifying maximum connections to much more than 5 when I initiate Sequel. 2. The actual updates I want to do are much bigger than the ones I posted, so using an IN clause ain't really an option. 3. I'm more curious about why this would happen rather than trying alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Your example can be reduced to: `DB[:objects].where(:XYZ=>false).update(:XYZ=>true)`

I'm guessing your actual need is not that simple.  But the same approach may still work. Instead of issuing a query per row, use a single query to update all related rows.

Comment: This specified UPDATE query is not the actual UPDATE query that I want to execute, it's just a pseudo one for demonstration purposes. The actual query is a lot longer and plays with JSON and stuff so I can't really update the entire table using a single query.

Answer (score 0):

I went through something similar on a project ("import all history from a legacy database into a new one with completely different structure and organization"). Unless you managed to shoot yourself in the foot somewhere else, you have 2 basic bottlenecks to look for:

1. the database's disk IO
2. the ruby process' CPU

Some suggestions,

1. database IO: use DB transactions, update 1000 records per transaction (you can tweak the exact number but 1000 is usually good) - huge DB table usually means a lot of indexes too, every couple of update actions will trigger a REINDEX and AUTOVACUUM actions within the DB which will result in a significant drop of update speed, a transaction basically allows you to push a 1000 updated records without REINDEX and AUTOVACUUM and then perform both actions, the result is MUCH faster (something like an order of magnitude)
2. database IO: change indexes, drop every index you can live without during the update process, ideally you will have only 1 very streamlined index which allows unique row lookups for update purposes
3. ruby CPU: unless you are using JRuby or Rubinius, or REALLY paying the price of network latency to your DB, threads will do you no big benefit, use fork/processes ([see GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock)). You did a great job choosing Sequel over AR for this
4. ruby CPU: if you decide to go threads + JRuby with this don't forget to try and plug in [jProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), it's amazing at tracing bottlenecks in Java and [author of SideKiq swears it is amazing for JRuby too](https://twitter.com/mperham/status/458001499654586368) - unfortunately, afaik, there is no equivalent of jProfiler for C Ruby (there are profiling tools, but nowhere as useful)

After you implement these suggestions you know you did all you could when:

1. all of the CPUs on the Ruby box are on 100% load
2. the hard disk IO of the DB is on 100% throughput

Find this sweet spot and don't add additional ruby update threads/processes after that (or add more hardware) and that's that

PS check out https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby - it's a great parallelization lib